# QuickBooks Online API - Add Connect Button

Tags: jsf, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using JSF and When adding connect button to my index.html in Google Chrome as follows;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
 xmlns:ipp=""   
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"    
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"     
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"     
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <f:view>   
 <h:head>       
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>      
 <script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js">


    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
        menuProxy: 'http://com.example/dispatch/BlueDotMenu',
        grantUrl: 'http://com.example/dispatch/RequestOAuthToken'       }); 

    </script>   </h:head>

 </f:view> 
 </html>
```

I get the follwoing error;

The value of the attribute "xmlns:ipp" is invalid. Prefixed namespace bindings may not be empty.

Is there a namespace value I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a workaround for JSF here. Worked for me.

You need to rewrite a bit the JavaScript file that QBO provides for the button and menu functionality. 
You can [download it from here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4009640/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js).

If you have implemented all the OAuth and stuff, then you just need to add the tags without 'ipp' prefix. Just insert like this:

```
<connectToIntuit></connectToIntuit>
<blueDot></blueDot>
```

No namespaces needed. JSF will just ignore unknown tag and the JS have the ability to insert html and events into it.

I've downloaded easyUI JS as well [from here](http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js). Insert the JS-es you've downloaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
```

It is required to insert jQuery version not less than 1.4.4.

The last thing left is the call of 'setup' js-function:

```
<script>
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
    menuProxy: '#{request.scheme}://#{request.serverName}#{request.contextPath}/qb_blueDotMenu.jsf',
    grantUrl: '#{request.scheme}://#{request.serverName}#{request.contextPath}/qb_requestToken.jsf'
    });
</script>
```

where **qb_blueDotMenu.jsf** - is the servlet that render BlueDotMenu and
**qb_requestToken.jsf** - is the RequestTokenServlet that gets the OAuth request token like show in QuickBooks Sample App.

Let me know if you got questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but I had the same issue and solved it by displaying the ipp:connectToIntuit button with

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.ippConnect}" escape="false"  />
```